# Oracle SQL : Cannot create a foreign key based on index of more than one column

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, foreign-keys

I'm not able to create a foreign key based on index of more than one column.

Adding the foreign key returns the error :

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list.

Below the code :

```
CREATE TABLE test_ek_uk (NOOPER VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL
                        ,NUMSEQ NUMBER NOT NULL
                        ,ANY_TEXT VARCHAR2(4000));

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_ek_uk_nooper_numseq ON test_ek_uk (NOOPER, NUMSEQ);


CREATE TABLE test_ek_fk (ID NUMBER UNIQUE NOT NULL, NOOPER VARCHAR2(7), NUMSEQ number);

ALTER TABLE test_ek_fk ADD CONSTRAINT test_ek_fk_FK FOREIGN KEY (NOOPER, NUMSEQ) REFERENCES test_ek_uk (NOOPER, NUMSEQ);
```

Comment: You need a unique constraint, not a unique index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Foreign Key references either a Primary Key constraint or a Unique constraint. And it must be a constraint, a unique index is not enough.

If you already have index then you can create unique constraint based on that index. For your case:

```sql
alter table test_ek_uk
  add constraint test_ek_uk_nooper_numseq unique (NOOPER, NUMSEQ)
  using index altest_ek_uk_nooper_numseq;
```

But if you don't have that index - there is no need to create it explicitly.
So, instead of creating the unique index you could create a unique constraint:

```sql
alter table test_ek_uk
  add constraint test_ek_uk_nooper_numseq unique (NOOPER, NUMSEQ);
```

The unique index is created in the background when you create this unique constraint.